# Get man page for different implementation of same command?

Tags: unix, gnu, manpages

On SunOS `man grep` gives me the man page for the SunOS grep but `grep --version` says it's grep (GNU grep) 2.5. How do I get the man page for GNU grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if the machine has installed a new grep, but didn't update the man page.  You have 4 options:

1. goto the web and read the [man page online](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)
2. try `info grep` instead. Often gnu packages come with info pages rather then man pages
3. Goto to ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/grep/ or an other mirror site and download grep 2.5 (maybe 2.5.4?).  Unpack it and you can install it, or in the docs dir you'll see a file `grep.in.1`.  This is the man page.  you can type:

   ```
   nroff -man grep.in.1 | more
   ```

   to view it
4. reinstall the package & documentation

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where your man pages are but I think the `-M` flag or setting MANPATH would be your friends here.

```
alias gnuman='MANPATH=/path/to/gnu/man/root man'
```

or

```
alias gnuman='man -M /path/to/gnu/man/root'
```

Comment: And in fact it would be best to set `MANPATH` following `PATH`, so that command lookup and man page lookup give matching results.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the order of your `MANPATH` to match the order of `PATH`.

If your `PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/home/myuser/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

set your `MANPATH` to:

```
/usr/local/man:/opt/local/man:/home/myuser/man:$MANPATH
```

(adjust as needed to reflect where your man pages actually are)